# jQuery unable to access form appended element

Tags: jquery, events, dom, append, element

Have a problem... I am appending a form element to a page with jQuery. However i cannot access the form element with js. I think this is because the dom has loaded and the form element isn't available in the dom. Is there a work around for this. I know I can append an Iframe with the form inside but would rather not.

Heres an example...

```
    <body>

    <div id=wrapper>
    </div>
       <div onlclick='newInput()'>
          Add Detail...
       </div>
    </body>
```

And the jQuery...

```
  function newInput(){

   var container = "<div id='input-container'><input id='input' type='text' value='insert new data here'></input><div id='submit onclick='submitInput()'>SUBMIT</div>";


   $('div#wrapper').append(container);

   }

   function submitInput(){

   var input = document.getElementById('input').value;

   ....do stuff with ne input here....
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you have two single quotes shown below ?

```
onclick='submitInput()''  <---
```

I would double check and make sure you're not getting any errors in the console, just in case the js is throwing an error. Your code works for me http://jsfiddle.net/4xxGJ/

Comment: my bad this is just an example. However It is not because of the type attribute. It's almost as if the element value dosent exist.

Comment: Appending with jQuery doesn't make the input invisible to the DOM. Probably the ID 'input' is invalid or something else is making the input invalid. Here's the proof: http://jsfiddle.net/fBghY/

Comment: Chris the code you posted, with some typos fixed works for me http://jsfiddle.net/4xxGJ/

Comment: Greg agreed, once appended to the DOM it's a part of the DOM and should be accessible just like any other element.